# Convert query sql

Tags: cakephp-2.0

how can I convert this query to be compatible with the find () function in cakephp

```
query : select role from table1 , table2
Where table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Please add *what you have already tried* (***in your question, not in the comments, as many new users seem to do***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$this->Model->query($yourQuery)`